# Transformar função em String com Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Supondo que tenho o seguinte objeto abaixo

```
const teste  = {
  onload:  ()=> {
    console.log('a')
  }
}
```

Onde o atributo onload é uma função, e preciso que seja transformado em uma string para que eu possa utilizar em outro local passando novamente para objeto, porém, se faço:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(teste))
```

Tenho como resultado `{}`

Teria alguma forma de converter todo objeto incluindo as funções que nele se encontra, em uma string?

Comment: Por que você precisa converte-lo em uma string? Não seria mais fácil enviar a referencia da função?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o segundo argumento do [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), para passar uma função de *replace*, que te permite modificar a forma como os dados são "serializados":

```js
const obj = {
  onload: () => console.log("Foo")
};

const json = JSON.stringify(
  obj,
  (name, val) => typeof val === 'function'
    ? val.toString()
    : val
);

console.log(json);
```

Estamos também usando o método [`Function.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/ToString).

Mas fazer isso não me parece uma boa ideia, ainda mais se esse tipo de dado for passar nas mãos de um usuário. Além disso, você estará utilizando JSON para transferir dados que ele não foi feito para trabalhar  – funções. Provavelmente há outras formas melhores de fazer o que você precisa.

Comment: E como passar novamente para Json em outro local? , tentei JSON.parse e me retorna {onload: "() => console.log("Foo")"}

Comment: Testei aqui e `json` é válido. Só que a função será convertida para string, e não função. Você terá que utilizar `eval` ou `new Function` para transformar de novo em uma função. Por isso essa abordagem é de fato insegura e talvez seja melhor reconsiderar utilizá-la.

Comment: Blz, muito obrigado pela explicação