# Objeto vazio javascript

Tags: javascript, string, objetos

Olá

tenho uma função que retorna um Objeto com varias funções dentro, eu preciso que este objeto seja retornado como string, porém quando faço o **JSON.stringfy()** ele retorna um objeto vazio.

Alguém pode me ajudar!

Segue o Codigo abaixo:

```
function run() {
    var start = ({

                "dinamico": function(opcao, params) {

                        var options = {

                            quickplies: (function(params){
                                    
                                var dinamico = {

                                            "type": "application/vnd.lime.select+json",
                                            "content":{
                                                "scope":"immediate",
                                                "text": params.title,
                                                "options": params.options 
                                            }
                                        }

                                    return dinamico

                            })(params)
                        }

                        return options[opcao]
                }
    })

    return JSON.stringify(start)
}

var funcoes = run();
console.log(funcoes)
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` não serializa funções (o seu objeto `start` só possui uma propriedade, que é uma função). Desse modo, tendo em vista que JSON não suporta funções, ela não será "colocada" na saída de `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: **[Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/461568/edit)** a sua pergunta para remover o código em imagem. Coloque o código formatado como texto entre `\`\`\``. Conforme você pode ver [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485), postar código como imagem **não** é uma boa prática neste site.

Comment: existe alguma maneira de exporta um objeto com funções dentro como string?

Comment: Talvez isto? [Transformar função em String com Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/454472/transformar-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-string-com-javascript)

Comment: Até existe, mas a conversão inversa pode abrir uma brecha de segurança (XSS) relativamente séria. Eu evitaria isso tanto quanto possível. Para que você quer serializar o objeto?

Comment: estou usando o blip para construção de chat bots, nele é possível  criar conteúdo dinâmicos tais como menu carrossel imagens etc..
eu quero deixa um objeto global exposto para que quando eu precisar criar alguns desses conteúdos  eu apenas chame a função especifica desse objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Jailson não entendi bem o porque disso, todavia. A forma que esta declarando o objeto 'start' não é comum.
Não é possível usar stringify em funções, mas se deseja prosseguir:

```
function run() {
var start = ({

            "dinamico": function(opcao, params) {

                    var options = {

                        quickplies: (function(params){
                                
                            var dinamico = {

                                        "type": "application/vnd.lime.select+json",
                                        "content":{
                                            "scope":"immediate",
                                            "text": params.title,
                                            "options": params.options 
                                        }
                                    }

                                return dinamico

                        })(params)
                    }

                    return options[opcao]
            }
})

return ''+ start.dinamico;
}

var funcoes = run();
console.log(funcoes)
```

A cima tem um código que acredito que fará o que quer.